# nm symbol utility reports

Tags: c, static-libraries, symbols, nm

nm command report a symbol to be both U and T. U stands for undefined, AFAIK the symbol is located in another library, but what does T mean ?

0000018c T _myfunc
         U _myfunc

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the man page for `nm(1)` we see:

```
 "T"
 "t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.
```

Comment: Sure, but if myfunc is in the code section, why would nm report it also as 'U' ?

Comment: The following answers your question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863613/what-does-symbol-value-from-nm-command-mean)

Comment: Oh I see, what was the source that made that happen?

Comment: And can you provide the entire `nm` output? It just looks very odd.