# Xcode custom framework strange partial linker error

Tags: xcode, frameworks, linker

I’ve made a custom c++ framework I’m trying to use within a c++ application developed using Xcode 4. However, I recently ran into some troubles: I’m getting three linker errors that I’m unable to resolve, like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "non-virtual thunk to netlib::base::BaseSocket::run()", referenced from:
   vtable for NetworkClient in network_client.o
```

I have this class, NetworkThread, declared in the framework, which has a abstract method run(). Another class inside the framework, BaseSocket, inherits from NetworkThread and implements this method. A third class, NetworkClient, is created in the application that uses the framework – and not within the framework itself – and inherits from the class BaseSocket, but compiling it triggers that linker error mentioned above.

I know decently how to solve linker errors, but now to the strange part about this one: I’m only getting linker errors on parts of the implementation in the class BaseSocket – some methods works fine (even new ones I add, proving that the framework and its paths are set up correctly). I’ve found a workaround which fixes the linker error. This is what the header declaration (of BaseSocket) looks like when the error occurs:

```
void run() override; // Will cause linker error
```

When I change the header like this (and re-names the method in the implementation to runX as well), it works fine:

```
void run() override { this->runX(); } 
void runX(); // Works like a charm!
```

I’ve deleted derived data folder, cleaned the project and removed the build-folder placed with the project.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** to summarize the issue you may say that the linker fails to “see” the implementation when the method is named “run” – while it works correctly when it’s called something else (runX() for instance), so if I make the implementation of run() inside the header(.h)-file which then calls the method runX (implemented in the cpp-file) that fixes the issue. It seems like a compiler and/or linker bug to me.

Comment: Hmm, can you post an example project? Hard to tell without more code.

Comment: I haven’t been able to reproduce the error in a smaller/example project by rewriting all the relevant sections, so I guess the error might occur because of the complex nature of the project. It’s way too much code to post it though in its current form. Is there any other way I can verify why the linker would behave like this? It is as if the linker would “see” some method-implementations (while not others) only from the name they have been given. Strange, I think.

Comment: Yah, it looks like the method re-implementation (runX) approach makes the the linker see the implementation in the Base class. Otherwise, the implementation is missing. I'm wondering if it can't find it b/c the implementation is in a framework. Perhaps add a static library instead as your target and use that inside your application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great post on what's going on with vtables, virtual functions, and inheritance:

http://arsenmk.blogspot.com/2013/02/a-little-more-about-virtual-functions.html

Also, you can see what the linker sees with the "otool" and "nm" commands at the command line. Such as:

```
$ nm /path/to/your.o
```

It will output a list of symbols, where "U" designates and undefined symbol, something like:

```
000000000000001b T foo
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```

Here's are some nice run downs of the options and output of the nm command:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds4%2Fnm.htm

[What does "symbol value" from nm command mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863613/what-does-symbol-value-from-nm-command-mean)