# Why are all symbols' values in my `.a` file 0

Tags: c++, linker

Long story short, I'm building `jsoncpp` through another library's build system (`webrtc`'s, which to say is behemoth would be an understatement). What that means is that I'm navigating through a build system I have little control over and have little familiarity with.

Suffice to say that when I build `libjsoncpp.a` on MacOS, the resulting file works perfectly fine. When I compile on Linux, linking with the resulting `.a` results in `undefined reference` for everything I use. Diving into the file, I noticed that while the MacOS version appears "normal", like so (excerpt):

```
0000000000001c10 T __ZNK4Json5ValueeqERKS0_
0000000000001c00 T __ZNK4Json5ValuegeERKS0_
0000000000001bc0 T __ZNK4Json5ValuegtERKS0_
0000000000003d10 T __ZNK4Json5ValueixEPKc
0000000000003de0 T __ZNK4Json5ValueixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

the same portion for the one built for Linux looks like this:

```
0000000000000000 T _ZNK4Json5ValuegeERKS0_
0000000000000000 T _ZNK4Json5ValuegtERKS0_
0000000000000000 T _ZNK4Json5ValueixEi
0000000000000000 T _ZNK4Json5ValueixEj
0000000000000000 T _ZNK4Json5ValueixEPKc
0000000000000000 T _ZNK4Json5ValueixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

Note that all the values are zero. I suspect that that's a clue to my problem but I just don't know what I'm supposed to conclude from it. I believe my issue with building on Linux is some compilation switch somewhere in the bowels of the build system and knowing what all the zeroes mean could help zero in on what to look for.

Edit: this has nothing to do with jsoncpp specifically. I'm hitting the same issue with other libs. I just picked that as an example.

Edit: Breakthrough. Here's a sample of the command line that's ultimately used to build one the three `.o` file and the linker command afterwards. Hope that helps.

```
[3/4] ../../../src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/jsoncpp/jsoncpp/json_reader.o.d -DJSON_USE_EXCEPTION=0 -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"332335-1\" -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=332543 -DCR_LIBCXXABI_REVISION=331450 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -I../../../src/third_party/jsoncpp/source/src/lib_json -I../../../src -Igen -I../../../src/third_party/jsoncpp/overrides/include -I../../../src/third_party/jsoncpp/source/include -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -B../../../src/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -no-canonical-prefixes -m64 -march=x86-64 -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-lambda-capture -Wno-user-defined-warnings -Wno-enum-compare-switch -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g2 -ggnu-pubnames -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../../src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang enforce-in-thirdparty-webkit -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-enum-max-value -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++ -isystem../../../src/buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include -isystem../../../src/buildtools/third_party/libc++abi/trunk/include -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../../src/third_party/jsoncpp/overrides/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp -o obj/third_party/jsoncpp/jsoncpp/json_reader.o
[4/4] python "../../../src/build/toolchain/gcc_ar_wrapper.py"  --output=obj/third_party/jsoncpp/libjsoncpp.a --ar="../../../src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar" " -r -c -s -D" @"obj/third_party/jsoncpp/libjsoncpp.a.rsp"
```

Comment: As it has nothing to do with jsoncpp, you should be able to provide a small example of the problem, complete with the command lines you are using to build things.

Comment: Well, you could have zero-based address in compiled object - it is, after all, address relative to the start of .text segment. But in typical object file only one symbol will have relative address of 0, all others would be at some different position. But if you have one source file per function, this might be ok

Comment: Let me link some answer here to clarify things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863613/what-does-symbol-value-from-nm-command-mean

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux It's not one source file by function. There's three source files in total. The same setup produces the expected output for MacOS.

Comment: @NeilButterworth My very problem is in the command lines used to produce this output. What you see is the smallest description of the problem I can make. I'm going backwards here, from the result and trying to figure what flag is injected in the resulting command that could produce this output. `webrtc's` build system is further wrpped in our own build system. The commands issued for those would tell you nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually nothing wrong with the values being `0`. Presumably, its a by-product of link-time optimization. When a final executable gets produced, the symbols will see their value addresses) assigned.

My actual problem was that I was mixing libraries built with `libc++` and other with `libstdc++`. The unresolved symbols referred to function that had things like `std::string` or `std::unique_ptr` as parameters. In this instance, `libjsoncpp.a` had symbols like `Json::Value(std::__1::basic_string)` (a constructor that takes a string) because it was build with clang and expecting to be linked with LLVM's `libc++` but I was ultimately attempting to link the final executable with GNU's `libstdc++` and the symbol `Json::Value(std::basic_string)` was unresolved.

Comment: Good one to know