# Incorrect output of `nm` on GCC LTO fat object files

Tags: c, gcc, nm, lto

If I have `tmp.c`:

```
char constantFOO[0x12];
char constantBAR[0x34];
```

I see `gcc -c tmp.c -o tmp.o && nm tmp.o` shows

```
0000000000000034 C constantBAR
0000000000000012 C constantFOO
```

But if I compile with `-flto -ffat-lto-objects`, `nm` outputs zeros for the symbol values:

```
00000000 C constantBAR
00000000 C constantFOO
```

I can the `34` and `12` values in a hexdump of both `.o` files.

My questions are

1. Is the behavior of `nm` on the LTO fat file expected? Am I just giving it input it's not expecting and it's outputting garbage?
2. What explains the original output (symbol value matching uninitialized array length)? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863613/what-does-symbol-value-from-nm-command-mean) didn't seem to help for the question of arrays, but maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled your `tmp.c` both with and without `-flto -ffat-lto-objects`, in `-S` mode (output assembly language), using GCC 8.3.  In both cases, the same basic definitions of your constants are emitted:

```
    .comm   constantFOO,18,16
    .comm   constantBAR,52,32
```

Most of the additional data emitted by LTO goes into ELF sections named `.gnu.lto_.something`.  LTO mode adds an additional marker object:

```
   .comm   __gnu_lto_v1,1,1
```

appears in the LTO-compiled object but not in the one without.

On its face, this shouldn't affect the output of `nm` for these symbols at all, and the lower-level tool `readelf -s` produces matching output for them:

```
$ readelf -s tmp-normal.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     7: 0000000000000010    18 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM constantFOO
     8: 0000000000000020    52 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM constantBAR

$ readelf -s tmp-lto.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 17 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     8: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     9: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
    10: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    11: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    12: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 
    13: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 
    14: 0000000000000010    18 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM constantFOO
    15: 0000000000000020    52 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM constantBAR
    16: 0000000000000001     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM __gnu_lto_v1
```

Therefore I believe that the behavior of `nm` is a bug, which should be reported to the maintainers of GNU binutils (see https://sourceware.org/binutils/).

As for the "original output" with symbol value matching array length, what's going on is that normally a symbol's value as shown by `nm` is its offset within its section of the object file.  Common symbols, however, are not in any section and do not have an offset, so `nm` prints the size of the symbol as its value.  This is, IIRC, historical behavior going all the way back to whichever iteration of System V added support for FORTRAN-like common data.  Notice how `readelf -s` prints 18 and 52 as the *sizes* of the objects, and the third argument to `.comm` (the desired alignment of each symbol) as their values.

If you compile with `-fno-common` you will see different output:

```
$ gcc -c -fno-common tmp.c -o tmp-nc.o
$ nm tmp-nc.o 
0000000000000020 B constantBAR
0000000000000000 B constantFOO
$ readelf -s tmp-nc.o | grep constant
     7: 0000000000000000    18 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 constantFOO
     8: 0000000000000020    52 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 constantBAR
```

because now your arrays are in the `.bss` section and have a defined offset within that section.

Note that `char constantFOO[0x12];` defines a *writable* array of 0x12 `char`s.  If you want it actually to be constant you need to say `const char`.  (And then it will be put in the `.rodata` section of the object file and the output of `nm` and `readelf` will be different yet again.)

Comment: I appreciate the comprehensive answer! I filed a bug here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24326